# ImageField está dando erro ao Salvar

Tags: django, forms

[Imagem do Formulário apresentando erro, porém imagem foi anexada.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNs9.png)

Olá Boa tarde a todos, estou estudando python e django ao mesmo tempo estou colocando em prática o meu estudo, nesse momento estou tendo um problema. Ao utilizar o ModelForm conforme os campos no model, quando vou salvar o formulário ele da um erro no campo da imagem, se eu trocar a opção do "required" para False ou blank=True ele salva o formulário sem problema, porém no Admin o model funciona corretamente. segue abaixo os códigos.

Alguém pode me auxiliar por favor?

Esse é meu models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Contacts(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=False, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    company = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    whatsapp = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False, blank=False)
    house_office = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
    image_contact = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d/')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Esse é meu forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Contacts


class NewContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contacts
        fields = "__all__"
```

Esse é meu Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from data import generator_jewel

from .forms import NewContactForm
from .models import Contacts

def new_contact(request):
    submitted = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact = form.save()
            contact.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contacts/new?submitted=True')
    else:
        form = NewContactForm
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True

    return render(request, 'jewelry/pages/newcontact.html', context={
        'form': form,
        'submitted': submitted,
    })
```

Assim está o meu html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-blank"></div>
<div class="container-main">
{% if submitted %}
    Contact registered successfully!
{% else %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
        
    </form> 
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Em settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'  
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Em url.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('jewelry.urls'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Você já chegou a fazer alguma configuração no settings.py para subir arquivos?

Comment: @KaiqueNakao sim, `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'`
Pelo admin, consigo cadastrar as imagens numa boa, o problema é somente quando uso o Form.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o motivo do problema, a solução é que precisa inserir enctype="multipart/form-data" no form, sem isso o request.FILE será sempre vazio.
Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).